# Persist property iOS

Tags: ios

I need a way of persisting a property whose value can be one of two states on iOS devices. The value must be accessible from all parts part of the application but invisible to other applications, easy to read and write and must survive one program run to the next and OS restarts. What option is the best for my situation on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your data set is small,I think `NSUserDefaults` should be a good option

```
//Save
NSUserDefaults * userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userdefaults setBool:true forKey:@"State"];
[userdefaults synchronize];

//Get
BOOL state = [userdefaults boolForKey:@"State"];
```

Comment: "If you want the state be accessible from the whole application,make a singleton or make this as one property of AppDelegate" Why? NSUserDefaults _is_ accessible from the whole application, so your one answer will do for both.

Comment: I just though that maybe every time read from `NSUserdefautls` will cause access to disk which is slow.You are right.I update my answer

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` seems to be what I need though I don't unerstand the issue which you are talking about.